# Sockets. Properly getting the response

Tags: c#, sockets

I have an issues with my http requests 'sometimes' failing.

```
var bodyBuilder = new List<byte>(4096);
var buffer = new byte[256];
while (socket.Available > 0) {
    var responseLength = socket.Receive(buffer, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);

    for (var i = 0; i < responseLength; i++)
        bodyBuilder.Add(buffer[i]);

    if (responseLength == 0)
        break; // never true btw
}
```

i read that `socket.Available > 0` should not be used since it doesn't indicate whether a socket is finished or not, but whether "if there is data this time"
https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/AvailableDoesntDoWhatYouThinkItDoes (albeit not C#, and not Sockets)

It makes sense because I'm getting exceptions when attempting to parse the response. Even when stepping through manually the debugger the data is receieve properly because i do it slowly when i step through

The solution would be to replace `while (socket.Available > 0)` with `while (true)` because the *responseLength* will be 0 once the server closes the connection. (according to many sources) But that is NOT what is happening. If i execute `socket.Recieve()` and there is no data available. The socket simply blocks indefinitely.

Any help?

Comment: just to be clear I'm not using any keep-alive headers.

Comment: So what does constitute the end of a message? You need some sort of marker/event whether it's an envelope that neatly contains the message (and contains a length field), a magic sequence in the byte-stream, or the disconnection of the socket (or something else like http chunked encoding). When you start thinking a bit more about this (and all the edge cases you might encounter on the way), it makes a higher level (proven) protocol seem quite attractive. Something like, say, HTTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Available` must be removed. A socket should usually have a single read outstanding. There should not be any check if there is data. Just read and work with the result.

> If i execute socket.Recieve() and there is no data available. The socket simply blocks indefinitely.

This means... that there is no data available. The other side has not sent more than what you already read.

You can solve this is two ways:

1. Determine that there is no more data through the protocol. For example, length-prefix your data. Then, you know how much to read.
2. Make the other side shut down the socket so that your read will end and return zero bytes read.

Comment: i'm using NancyFX. It's should be using a standard protocol. It's also out of my hands.

Comment: MSDN states : If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block until data is available

Comment: MSDN also states : If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will read as much data as is available, up to the size of the buffer. If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method will complete immediately and return zero bytes. #DefineConnectionOrientedSocket

Comment: @CyberFox it is true what you said. What do you mean by that? Is your question answered?

Comment: uh, Sorry for late response, no it didn't help sorry, i did find a solution tho. using HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1 fixed the issues. Now socket.Receive will return 0 and not block anymore. Not sure if this is sustainable solution.

Comment: @CyberFox in HTTP 1.1 you must parse the Content-Length header and ready exactly that many bytes. Using HTTP 1.0 would be a working fix but performance is slower because you need a new TCP connection for each request. I that's OK then that is a fix. In any case Available must be removed.

Comment: thank you the response. i want to ask. you say i need to create a new tcp connect for each request? Isn't that how HTTP normally works? Request > Receive > Close

Comment: @CyberFox HTTP has keep alive which reuses the same connection for more requests. That's a major efficiency gain.